# SharePoint Online - Registration on Event Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, calculated-column, calendar, events

I am trying to build a event calendar that allows users to register to events. Columns for this calendar will be Title, Location, Date, Occupancy limit(Number). This will be filled by event manager while creating the event.

For the registration form(probably a list form), I want to show the Event Title, Location, Date, Occupancy Limit, Number of spots left so users can understand what they are registering for. Then users register by providing their details.

**How to associate this list to the event calendar?
There will be at least 10 events every month. How to associate every registration(list item) to a particular event?**

Please suggest?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the registration list you can use a lookup column into the calendar.

Comment: Hello teylyn, Thanks for replying. How to manage to show number of spots left and end the registration once the the limit reaches?

Comment: That's a totally different question. If you use Infopath, you'll need to filter the registration list by the current event and perform a count of the records shown. Not something for a beginner. It involves quite complex XPath. But again, this would be a different question.

Comment: @Gaurravs, yes it DOES provide an answer to the question. I'm not critiquing or requesting clarification. My post simply states how to do what is asked in the OP with SharePoint. If you don't understand that, please skip the review.